# How To Make List Box Transparent? WPF

Tags: wpf, background, listbox

```
 <telerik:RadExpander  Header="View My Team" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="274" Margin="34,170,0,450" FontSize="20">
        <ListBox x:Name="myTeam" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="214" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" Margin="0,0,-103,-1" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
            <MenuItem Header="Ben Clarke" Background="Transparent"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Jack Davies" Background="Transparent"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Harry Potter" Background="Transparent"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Bill Gates" Background="Transparent"/>
        </ListBox>
    </telerik:RadExpander>
```

I have this code where my list box is inside the expander which is all working fine, but i cannot get the list box to be transparent background so that it just shows the names and then the roll-over effect etc ... The background is just appearing white.

As you can see i have added the background Transparent to all the MenuItems and the Listbox itself and it still hasn't worked :(

Comment: Did you try to add the AllowsTransparency="True" property in your window/page?

Comment: @Santux Just tried that and still no luck any other suggestions?

Comment: I would have to try that myself. Do you know a tool called [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)? That's great for these kind of situations! It enables you to browse the visual tree of a running WPF application and change some properties as you go...

Comment: I have confirmed that the default `ListBox` template in WPF supports transparent background, and that setting the background to `Transparent` will achieve the desired effect. Your problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some usage of the Opacity property can do it? Either on the ListBox or on the MenuItems (don't know if they got Opacity property)?

Comment: I've just tried playing around with the opacity and it does it to the text aswell.

Comment: Is there a background property on the RadExpander?

Comment: Yes and i have set it to Transparent.